# Sending data to other page with bloc cubit

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

My problem is this. I created cubit for 2 different pages. When I am on the first page, I can fill the list inside the 2nd page and I can read it from the log. However, when I go to the second page, the list I filled in from the previous page is still empty.

> Main.dart

```
home:
          
          
           MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider(create: (_) => HomeCubit(PhotoService())),
              
              BlocProvider(create: (_)=> FavoritesCubit())//Gerekiyor,homeviewda içerisindeki methoda erişmem gerekiyor
            ],
            child: const HomeView())
```

> HomeView.dart

```
where I run the function in favoritescubit and add it to the list
 onTap: () {
                        

                        BlocProvider.of<FavoritesCubit>(context).addFavorite(
                            context,
                            state.selectItem![index],
                            );
                        print(state.selectItem?[index].isSelected);
                        context.read<FavoritesCubit>().getAllFavorites();

                        // print("UI --- ${state.selectItem![index].isSelected}");
                        //  context.read<FavoriteBloc>().add(
                        //      AddFavorite(photoList, photoList.isSelected));
                        //  print(" ispressed ${photoList.isSelected}");
                      },
```

> FavoritesCubit.dart

```
class FavoritesCubit extends Cubit<FavoritesState> {
  FavoritesCubit() : super(const FavoritesState());

  final List<PhotoModel> favoriteList = <PhotoModel>[];

  Future<void> getAllFavorites() async {
    print("FavoriteList : ${favoriteList.length}");
    emit(state.copyWith(favoriteList: favoriteList));
  }



 

     Future<void> addFavorite(
        BuildContext context,
        PhotoModel photo,
      ) async {
        photo.isSelected = !photo.isSelected;
        if (favoriteList.contains(photo) == false) {
          favoriteList.add(photo);
          emit(state.copyWith(
              favoriteList: favoriteList, isFavorite: photo.isSelected));
          print("${state.favoriteList!.length}asdasd");
        } else if (favoriteList.contains(photo) == true) {
          favoriteList.remove(photo);
          emit(state.copyWith(
              favoriteList: favoriteList, isFavorite: photo.isSelected));
          print("${state.favoriteList!.length}asdasd");
        }
```

> FavoriteView.dart

```
class FavoriteView extends StatefulWidget {
  const FavoriteView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FavoriteView> createState() => _FavoriteViewState();
}

class _FavoriteViewState extends State<FavoriteView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => FavoritesCubit()..getAllFavorites(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Bloc Example"),
        ),
        body: buildFavoriteList(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}




Widget buildFavoriteList(BuildContext context) {
 
  return BlocConsumer<FavoritesCubit, FavoritesState>(
    listener: (context, state) {
      // TODO: implement listener
    },
    builder: (context, state) {
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: state.favoriteList?.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: (() {
                // navigateToPostDetailPage(context, photos[index]);
              }),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: PhotoListTile(
                  isPressed: state.favoriteList![index].isSelected,
                  imageUrl: state.favoriteList![index].thumbnailUrl.toString(),
                  title: state.favoriteList![index].title.toString(),
                  url: state.favoriteList![index].url.toString(),
                  onTap: () {
                    // context.read<HomeCubit>().addFavorite(
                    //     context,
                    //     state.favoriteList![index],
                    //     state.favoriteList![index].isSelected);
                    // context
                    //     .read<FavoriteBloc>()
                    //     .add(RemoveFavorite(photos[index]));
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          });
    },
  );
```

Comment: Can you clarify: "...I can fill the list inside the 2nd page and read it from the log". That part doesn't make sense to me. Secondly, where is the second page located in the widget tree compared to the MultiBlocProvider and the HomeView (which I guess is the "first page") ?

Comment: My 1st page is home My 2nd page is my favorite sir. I have added the favoriteview to my mail. What I am trying to do is to list the cards I like in my listview in homeview on the 2nd page. What I want to say is that when I am in the first homeview, I can add to the empty list in the favoriteCubit successfully, but when I go to the favoriteview, my list is still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, now with your added information about your `FavoriteView` it is clear what the problem is.

In your `FavoriteView` you create a new cubit, which is not the same as you created in the `MultiBlocProvider`. That is why it is always empty on your `FavoriteView`

```
create: (context) => FavoritesCubit()..getAllFavorites(), // This is the issue
```

Make sure that your `FavoriteView` is a child somewhere under your `MultiBlocProvider` and remove the creation of a new `FavoritesCubit` in that view. I.e. remove the `BlocProvider` in your `FavoriteView`

Comment: thank you sir.this wasn't my only problem but it helped me solve it and i realized my mistake.

Comment: Yeah you didn't do exactly as I said :) Your FavoriteView isn't a child widget of your MultiBlocProvider. This is a separate issue from the one you've posted here. In my opinion, this (your) original problem is "solved". If you search for "Could not find the correct Provider", then you'll find a bunch of solutions to your new problem". One easy way to fix your problem is to wrap your entire MaterialApp with your MultiBlocProvider, but that isn't optimal perhaps? Depends on what your app should do in the long run etc...